# jquery for displaying each dropdown in woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to customize 'woocommerce'. Each product has its own variables. I want to display the selected option in front of each drop down. 
Each product has different numbers of drop downs 'some of them more than one' and I want to display each drop down selected value in front of its own drop down. I could write for one drop down but because the number of drop downs are different I can't do it correctly. can you  help me with the jQuery code?

[image]

```
$('select#soflow').on('change', function() {
  var count = $("select#soflow option:selected").text();
  var value = $("select#soflow option:selected").text();
  $("#textvalue").append().html("<span>" + value + "</span>");
})
```

Comment: Share what you tried so far, even for one dropdown

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#soflow').on('change',function(){
        var  count =  $("select#soflow option:selected").text();

            var value = $("select#soflow option:selected").text();
            $("#textvalue").append().html("<span>" + value+"</span>");
        })
        });

Comment: this code shows the selected option of each dropdown next together without any space

Answer (score 1):

Since your question has no answer, I just tried to solve your problem somehow, ofcourse it's absolutely blindly, because I don't see any `html` or this is not common element, I don't see this section in a sample woocommerce website, anyway. You can use below code to get your result but be aware this is `select` all `select` elements in your page, so consider to look for a `class` on your `select` element or select by parent for ex. `.someDiv select` or `etc` to work without any conflict.

In this example, find all `select option` and on change event find `selected` value and append as `span` by `.dropdown-selected` class next to your select option.

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  $(this).on('change', function() {
    $(this).next().closest('.dropdown-selected').remove();
    var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $("<span class='dropdown-selected'>" + value + "</span>").insertAfter($(this));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown" id="soflow">
  <option>Text 1</option>
  <option>Text 2</option>
  <option>Text 3</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select class="dropdown" id="soflow2">
  <option>Text 4</option>
  <option>Text 5</option>
  <option>Text 6</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select class="dropdown" id="soflow3">
  <option>Text 7</option>
  <option>Text 8</option>
  <option>Text 9</option>
</select>
```

*I can't help you much more, just try this if you any question, comment it!*